# PHP Form attach CSV

Tags: php, csv

I've been searching all day and have not found the code that works.  I'm trying, after submitting form,

1. Validate - This works
2. Check to see if record exists - This works
3. Insert record -  This works
4. Attach a CSV that has the form variables - This does not work

This is a scaled down version

```
<?php 

$to = "email@email.com";


if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{ 

// VALIDATION

  if(empty($_POST['address'])) 
  { 

   "First Name Required";

  } 


 if(empty($_POST['email'])) 
  { 

   "Last Name Required"; 

  }


  if(empty($error))  
  { 

    $subject = 'The Form';
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; \r\n" ;
    $headers .= "From: from@theemailaddress.com\r\n"."Reply-to: {$_POST['email']}\r\n"; 


   $msg .="<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <table>
    <tr><td>
        <table>
           <tr><td>This is the email sent.</td></tr>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>";


     include('con.php');

     $con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$dbName);
     if (!$con)
      {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
      }

      mysqli_select_db($con,"thetable");


    $email= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
    $address= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['address']);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM thetable WHERE `email` = '{$email}' OR `address` = '{$address}'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    if(($result->num_rows)>= 1)
    {
    $theerror = "You exist"; 
    }

    else
       {
$sql="INSERT INTO thetable(email, address) VALUES ('$_POST[email]','$_POST[address]'";

    $success = "Sent ... Insert it!!!"; 


          if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
          {
          die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
          }

             //The Attachment

            $cr = "\n";
            $data = "Email" . ',' . "address" . ',' . $cr;
            $data .= "$email" . ',' . "$address" . $cr;
            $fp = fopen('diploma_apprenticeship_form_sub.csv','a');
            fwrite($fp,$data);
            fclose($fp);

            $attachments[] = Array(
               'data' => $data,
               'name' => 'diploma_apprenticeship_form_sub.csv',
               'type' => 'application/vnd.ms-excel'
            );


            //Generate a boundary string

            $semi_rand = md5(time());
            $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";


            //Add the headers for a file attachment


            $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
                       "From: {$from}\n" .
                       "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
                       " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";


            //Add a multipart boundary above the plain message


            $msg= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
                      "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
                      "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
                      "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
                      $text . "\n\n";


            //Add sttachments

            foreach($attachments as $attachment){
               $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($attachment['data']));
               $name = $attachment['name'];
               $type = $attachment['type'];

               $msg.= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
                          "Content-Type: {$type};\n" .
                          " name=\"{$name}\"\n" .
                          "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
                          $data . "\n\n" ;
            }

            $msg.= "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";

           $result = @mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers); 
        }


       mysqli_close($con);


      { 

      } 
    } 
  } 

?>
```

Comment: Why won't you use any normal class, like, for example, phpmailer, for attachments and email??

Comment: Because it would take hours and hours to make those changes.  All I want it to attach a csv have any ideas?

Comment: You already spent more time trying to create mail from the scratch.  And you'll spend more time trying to find a problem (at least the source of the generated email should be shown for that). Trust me, phpmailer will do it much faster and shorter.

Comment: phpmailer doesn't have the advanced validation as I have so I don't like it. Note the validation is scaled down in the code you see here.  Can anyone out there help?

Comment: `phpmailer doesn't have the advanced validation`??? I'm not sure that you fully understand what you are writing about. phpmailer has nothing to do with the validation of the data from form. Its only purpose is to prepare emails (with attachments/inlines and so on) and submit them further to sendmail or smtp server. Show the example  of the generated by your code email, to see where the problem is.

Comment: My apologies thought you were talking about those already made forms.  Look at my code and put in phpmailer and see if you can get it to work.  I am worn out so that's why I came here for help.  Hoping someone will look at my code and say here's the issue.

Comment: It is very simple, look here - http://phpmailer.worxware.com/?pg=tutorial#3 and here http://phpmailer.worxware.com/?pg=examplebsendmail Method `AddAttachment($path,$name,$encoding,$type);` has only first required argument, second one is just the name of the file (how it will be named as attachment), encoding of the attachment and content-type. All three phpmailer will try to create by itself, based on the attached file.

Comment: For sure, use something like PHPmailer or rMail, you don't want to monkey with email headers, that can be a big pain in the brain, even the wrong line endings can cause issues with them.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing it but I don't see anything to grab the variables I'm inserting into the db and also place them in the csv file.  I'm not intermediate php here.

Comment: Can some one show me using phpmailer on how to do what I said above?

Comment: There is a lot wrong with that code, for example  just putting "First Name Required"; is not gonna do much surprised it doesn't throw an error.  As for the question, create a file for the csv data, then attach that file.  Also as I said your mixing line endings in your email headers.

Comment: ArtisiticPhoenix no kidding... I said above this is a scaled down version... please read.  I don't need your help with the validation but rather attaching the csv... it really gets me that people here can code php but can't read a post.  Why is that? It's like me telling you, you spelled your name wrong - artisitic instead of artistic  when I have no idea why you did that but I'm sure you did it for a reason.  Also why would I post the validation fully when it works?  If I'm mixing the line endings show me where that is happening then everything is solved.

Comment: @motocrz - one would do wise to appreciate the help.  That said "MIME-Version: 1.0 \r\n", "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" it fairly obvious.  As I said try creating a csv file, $f = fopen(path to file, 'w'), fputcsv( $f, $data); fclose( $f ); attach file with mailer as per its documentations.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix I do appreciate the help when it's given.

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't work.  I get the email but no attachment.

Comment: @motocrz What doesn't work? I'd can the attitude, and look at my answer.  Trust me it's not as hard as you are making it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$f = fopen('path to file', 'w'); //path such as __DIR__./file.csv';  write mode.

fputcsv( $f, $data);
//data is an array of data ie array('one', 'two'); is one,two in the file ~ make a loop
//around this and write as many lines as you need, like array(header, header1); then
//array(data, data1) etc...

fclose($f); //close the file when done
```

http://phpmailer.worxware.com/

```
 require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

 $mail = new PHPMailer;
 $mail->From = 'from@example.com';
 $mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');
 $mail->addAttachment( __DIR__.'/file.csv');  
 $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
 $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';

 $mail->send();

 unlink( __DIR__.'/file.csv' ); //remove the file
```

Oh and get rid of all that header stuff, let php mailer do its job, which as you mentioned is not to validate your data.  Work up a process flow.

Input
Validate
Calculate ( assign values )
Output ( send your email )
Clean up ( remove any files, etc.. )

etc..

AS An update

```
$msg .="<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<table>
<tr><td>
    <table>
       <tr><td>This is the email sent.</td></tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>";
```

... and then latter

```
$msg= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
                  "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
                  "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
                  "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
                  $text . "\n\n";
```

Also your likely to get a warning for the first message as you are not defining the variable before using the concant on it.

```
 $msg .= 'something';
```

Should be

```
  $msg = 'something';
```

Or

```
  $msg = '';
  $msg .= 'something';
```

Comment: Thanks ArtisticPhoenix "MIME-Version: 1.0 \r\n", "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" fixed it. I noticed when I copied and paste his suggestion I accidentally copied the double quote.  It's working now without phpmailer.

Comment: I'd still use php mailer, different severs will have different header requirements.  but it's your choice.

Comment: I'll change it later to phpmailer.  Can you tell me why I only get the attachment and not the email?  I was so happy to see the attachment that the actual email body isn't there.

Comment: Its because you are reassigning the $msg variable.

Comment: Right so I named it to $msgemail but got code only in the email.. sorry forgot to mention that.

Comment: Probably something in the headers, they are difficult to do, that's why people took the time for writing things like PhpMailer.  There is a content HTML email header or such .. I don't know I use libraries for it ... lol